# hg reset local repository to the state of remote one

Tags: mercurial

how can I reset my local repository, to the state of remote one?

I have commited local changes (didn't push).

I want to delete all the differencies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Make a new clone of the remote repo and throw away the old clone.
2. Make a new clone of the local repo, but limit it to the last revision in the remote.  (e.g. `hg clone -r <last remote changeset> <local_repo_old> <local_repo_new>`).
3. Use the [`hg strip`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension#Strip) command from the [mq extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) to remove the changesets from your local repo

NOTE: When trying options 2 or 3, you can use the [`hg outgoing`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/outgoing) command to see which changesets have not yet been pushed to the remote repo.

Comment: strip it is, thanks - repository is just too big for me to download it in reasonable time :)

Comment: This answer would be perfect if it would include information regarding how to get the change numbers that you want to strip.

Comment: @SorinSbarnea: See the note added to my answer.

Comment: mq link is dead